# Hibernate materializing non-existing Entity

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We have an odd situation here, where Hibernate tries to materialize an entity, which is not there.

We have two entities, `A` and `B`, roughly like this:

```
public class A {
...
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "aId")
private int id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
private B b;
}

public class B {
...
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "aId")
private int id;

@JoinColumn(name = "bId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private A a;
```

B has a primitive `int` column, which is backed by a non-null database column of type integer. We are doing a `EntityManager#find` for a single Instance of `A`. As `B` is loaded eagerly (as per default of the `@OneToOne`), this find is translated into a statement joining A- and B- Tables with a left outer join on the common ID.

This code has been working since roughly 2004 without a quirk. Now it doesn't.

The symptom is a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`, with the text saying, that a `null` value has been assigned to a primitive value which failed.

The stacktrace clearly states, we are in the case, where we do a find for a single, numeric primary key. Nonetheless the statement logged by hibernate is structured with the following where part: `a0_.AID in (?, ?)` where the parameters are bound to two different IDs. We cannot tell, whether this is normal, however, what happens next is, that two `A`s are found, one with an attached `B`, one without. The logging shows, that for the first row all fields of `B` are present and a complete `A` instance (including subentity `B`) is generated. In the next step, the second row is parsed. Here, all `B` columns are empty, except the id (outer join). Nonetheless, a `B` subentity is generated and this failes, once hibernate tries to put `null` into the `int` field.

We are using Hibernate 4.1.12.Final (Yep, we are ashamed as well, nope, update is impossible), all of this happens on a Oracle 12c with recent driver packes. Everything is deployed on a Wildfly 9 (meh, doesn't get better, we know).

The questions are:

1. How on earth does hibernate come to the conclusion, that searching for one `A` should be done by putting in two IDs?
2. Where does the second ID come from?
3. Why does Hibernate try to create a B instance, where there is none to create?

Kind regards,
Jonathan

**EDIT**
We have found out, that the root cause seems to be, that sometimes Oracle returns the ID of `B`, although there is no entry in the table, so basically `select * from A left outer join B on A.aId = B.aId where A.aid = 1` returns a row with `B.aId = 1` although `select * from B where B.aid = 1` returns an empty rowset.

We assume this is a bug in the Oracle RDBMS and try to solve it by server-restart and Schema re-Import.

Hibernate interprets the existence of the ID such that it assumes, the whole entity is there, tries to populate the entity and in the process fills the `int` field with `null`.

This leaves open: Why does Hibernate select with a in clause and where does the second ID come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to questions 1 & 2 are simply: Hibernate deferred multiple selects to the latest possible moment and when required to execute, executed them in one statement. So we had two selects, where one was not required to be executed immediatly. This was the second ID.

As for 3: It was a meanwhile fixed bug in Oracle DBMS.